# How can i run tarantool 2.3.1 with the snapshot from tarantool 1.10.3

Tags: tarantool

Circumstances:

For 3 years there is an application, that uses tarantool (now it is 1.10.3), and once upon a time we've decided to move it to Kubernetes and replace old and ugly dockerfile, based on Jessie to the official image tarantool/tarantool:2.3.1. I don't know will it be all fine with the data.

In this case, I have two questions, and I will be really happy to read the correct answers from you:

1. Does tarantool 2.3.1-2-g92750c828 support recovering from snapshots, made by tarantool 1.10.3?
2. How can I surely load the snapshot data by the new version? It would be great to make it without restarting tarantool, because I have PVC like "emptyDir" that can't handle any data when pod restarts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, Tarantool 2.3 is compatible with Tarantool 1.10 in terms of binary protocol and snapshot format. If you can't simply run Tarantool 2.3 based on snapshot of 1.10, please file an issue - https://github.com/tarantool/tarantool/issues

I want to note several things: after upgrade to 2.3 it could be impossible to run it back on 1.10 (some system spaces/records incompatible will be created).

2. Sorry, I can't answer for this question for Kubernetes. But you can't simply stop and run again single instance. But upgrade without downtime is available for replication cluster - https://www.tarantool.io/en/doc/2.4/book/admin/upgrades/#upgrading-tarantool-in-a-replication-cluster